# How to make pull to refresh in tableview buttom in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pull-to-refresh

Want to add the pull to refresh in bottom of tableview.

First want to show the numbers in tableview 100 to 90.

Then add the pull to refresh in bottom of tableview. pull it want to display 80 to 70, then pull refresh 70 to 60, then pull refresh 50 to 40... etc final 1 to 10 means get stoped display "no data available". how to achieve this. help me thanks advance.

Here my code.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dataTbl: UITableView!
    var numbers: [Any] = ["90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100"] // display first 100 to 90.
```

Loaded in tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numbers.count
    }



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.dataTbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.numbers[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }
```

searched in google for add the refresh in buttom of tableview. i got this code.

```
let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
 spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
 spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
 tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
```

show spinner using

```
spinner.startAnimating()
```

hide it using

```
spinner.stopAnimating()
```

By using this code how to do pull to refresh help me.

Comment: But can't achieve it. -- means whats ...

Comment: what you want to do with above code?

Comment: where you called this `let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
 spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray`

Comment: pull to refresh in buttom of tableview, first display 100 to 90 then pull to refresh 80 to 90 like move with 10 to  1 means finally display no data

Comment: ru get my question?

Comment: i dnt know where to call ?

Comment: let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray) spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray

Comment: callthis in scrollview delegate and get your arraycount -1 object < 10 do nothing else add 10 10 objects in your array and reload the table

Comment: for add spinner at bottom of tableview try to create one view which contain spinner and when you reach at bottom assign view and tableview footer view and once your data loaded remove table footer view or make it as nil

Answer (score 3):

Use following delegate to detect the end of the table and to add spinner logic with table footer.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if tableView.contentOffset.y >= (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height) {
                    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
     spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
     spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
     tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
            }
        }
```

Once you append those more entries to your data source then remove footer view

```
tableView.tableFooterView = nil
```

Comment: how to refresh elements 100 to 90 , 90 to 80, 80 to 70

Comment: If you are fetching it from server then you need to send offset to server to fetch next 10 records, when you get response from server then append those records to the previous data source

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the below code,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if tableView.contentOffset.y >= (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height) {
            //you reached the bottom of tableview, you can append the other 10 numbers to array and do reload
    }
}
```

You don't need to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to achieve this, i hope `UITableViewDelegate` is enough. As `UITableview` inherits the property of `UIScrollView`
Hope this helps